# ASP.NET MVC calculating Shipping total

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

How do I calculate the shipping total in razor html. Shipping charges are $3.99 for the first item and $.99 for each additional item.

```
 @{
     double itemTotal = 0;
     double subTotal = 0;
     int totalQty = 0;
     double discount = 0.8;
     double shippingBase = 3.99;
     double shippingItem = 0.99;

 }

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {

        double price = (double)item.price / 100 * discount;
        itemTotal = @item.qty * price;
        subTotal += itemTotal;
        totalQty += @item.qty;
```

Comment: Just FYI you might want to consider moving that out of your view and into a view model. It's a business rule, so tying it into your view means you can only use that view. You can use view helpers but since this is a business rule it probably belongs in a method in the model or in a separate business logic class/etc. The controller can then build the view model by supplying exactly the values that are needed, and the view model can just display what is there without doing any calculations like this. Just a suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Using this statement

> Shipping charges are $3.99 for the first item and $.99 for each
>   additional item.

the following data was extracted to create a shipping charge model.

```
public class ShippingCharge {
    public decimal basePrice { get; set; }
    public int baseCount { get; set; }
    public decimal unitPrice { get; set; }
}
```

Which using the example from the OP would be populated as

```
//Shipping charges are 
shippingCharge = new ShippingCharge() {
    // $3.99 
    basePrice = 3.99M,
    //for the first item 
    baseCount = 1,
    // $.99 for each additional item. 
    unitPrice = 0.99M
};
```

With that done the following algorithm was used to calculate the shipping charge given an item count.

```
decimal? CalculateShippingTotal(int itemCount, ShippingCharge charge) {
    decimal? total = null;
    if (charge != null) {
        var basePrice = charge.basePrice;
        var baseCount = charge.baseCount;

        if (itemCount > baseCount) {
            var qtyDifference = itemCount - baseCount;
            var additionalCost = qtyDifference * charge.unitPrice;

            total = basePrice + additionalCost;
        } else {
            total = itemCount * basePrice;
        }
    }
    return total;
}
```

The following unit tests verify the correctness of the algorithm in calculating total shipping charges.

```
[TestMethod]
public void _TotalShipping_For_One_Item() {
    //Arrange
    var totalQty = 1;
    var expected = 3.99M;

    //Act
    var actual = CalculateShippingTotal(totalQty, shippingCharge);

    //Assert
    actual.ShouldBeEquivalentTo(expected);
}

[TestMethod]
public void _TotalShipping_For_Two_Items() {
    //Arrange
    var totalQty = 2;
    var expected = 4.98M;

    //Act
    var actual = CalculateShippingTotal(totalQty, shippingCharge);

    //Assert
    actual.ShouldBeEquivalentTo(expected);
}

[TestMethod]
public void _TotalShipping_For_Three_Items() {
    //Arrange
    var totalQty = 3;
    var expected = 5.97M;

    //Act
    var actual = CalculateShippingTotal(totalQty, shippingCharge);

    //Assert
    actual.ShouldBeEquivalentTo(expected);
}
```

This answer target specifically how to calculate the shipping cost based on OP not the subtotal with discount. That should be simple enough for you to calculate by tallying the items, quantities and prices. Once done use item count and charges to calculate the shipping costs.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a simple condition and addition to your loop:

```
@{
    double itemTotal = 0;
    double subTotal = 0;
    int totalQty = 0;
    double discount = 0.8;
    double shippingBase = 3.99;
    double shippingItem = 0.99;
    double totalShipping = 0; //used to calculate the cumulative shipping total
}

@foreach (var item in Model)
{

    double price = (double)item.price / 100 * discount;
    itemTotal = @item.qty * price;
    subTotal += itemTotal;
    totalQty += @item.qty;
    totalShipping += ((totalShipping >= shippingBase) ? shippingItem : shippingBase);
}
```

Comment: Im confused about this statement: totalShipping += totalShipping > shippingBase ? shippingItem : shippingBase;

Comment: It's a "tertiary operator": https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx. It's essentially like an "if" statement, but more concise. In this example, every iteration through the loop (for each item), "something" is added to `totalShipping`. If `totalShipping` is less than `3.99`, (that indicates it's the first time through the loop) then `3.99` is added to `totalShipping`. If the `totalShipping` is greater than `3.99` (every additional item after the first item), then `shippingItem` (`0.99`) is added to `totalShipping`.

Comment: Ok I tried testing it but it is not adding 0.99 when its the second item

Comment: Hmmm, I wonder if it is an order of operations issue there. Is it adding anything at all the second time around?  You might try putting that expression in parentheses. Check my updated answer.

Comment: You know what, I think that needs to be greater than **or** equal, not just greater than. Check my updated answer again. Sorry about that.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. It is still not adding the second value 0.99